# Do R @data and coordinates() preserve structure?

Tags: r

I need to assign centroids for census blocks to a data frame, my way of doing so is listed below. Since gCentroids doesn't return any UID, if I cbind the centroid coordinates() to the census @data will the centroids be assigned to their correct corresponding census blocks?

```
census=CENSUS@data

CENTROIDS = gCentroid(CENSUS,byid=TRUE)

centroids=as.data.frame(coordinates(CENTROIDS))

censcent=cbind(census, centroids)

df=merge(df, censcent, by=geoid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. The row.names are serving as IDs and keep everything linked. You can check with, e.g.

```
plot(CENSUS[1, ])
plot(CENTROIDS[1, ], add = TRUE)
```

Any two matching rows should result in a polygon and point appearing on the plot.

if you really want to make sure of this, you could do something like

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)

nc_4267 <- readOGR(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = 'sf'))
# make the row names into a new column
nc_4267$rownames <- as.character(row.names(nc_4267))
# rgeos always expects projected coordinates:
nc_26917 <- spTransform(nc_4267, CRSobj = CRS("+init=EPSG:26917"))

cent_26917 <- gCentroid(nc_26917, byid = T, id = nc_26917$rownames)
cent_4267 <- spTransform(cent_26917, CRSobj = nc_4267@proj4string)
cent_4267$x_coord <- cent_4267@coords[, 1]
cent_4267$y_coord <- cent_4267@coords[, 2]
# again, get row names into a column
cent_4267$rownames <- as.character(row.names(cent_4267))

# use the row names columns to join the data instead of cbind
nc_4267@data <- dplyr::left_join(nc_4267@data, cent_4267@data, by = 'rownames')
```

but that's overkill IMO. If you want to try the new 'sf' package instead,

```
library(sf)

ncsf <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = 'sf')) 
ncsf <- st_transform(ncsf, 26917)
ncc  <- st_centroid(ncsf)
```

I rather prefer this one; the data structure is easier to see, st_centroid refuses to calculate in lat/long instead of silently returning possibly dodgy locations, and all the polygon attributes are transferred to the centroid points.